# Python adding a number to another number to get a number divisible by 10

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, modulo

for example    k = (93 + k) % 10
               return k
Is there an algorithm that will get me to return 7?

Comment: `return -whatever`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is simply  `a=(-k % 10)` .

The explanation is basic modulo arthmetic : `(a+k) %10= a%10 + k%10 = -k %10 + k%10 = 0 %10`

Comment: thank you! ive been stuck on that small part for awhile!

Comment: @CooperKoenig Glad I could help, consider accepting the answer if you found it satisfactory  (button on the left)